# Line segment in the unit sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to prove the following statement

---

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, with linearly independent vectors $x,y$, such that $\|x\|=1=\|y\|$, with $\|x\|+\|y\|=\|x+y\|$, then there is a line segment in the unit sphere of $X$.

---

My attempt:

**1.** The unit sphere is the set:$$S=\{a\in X:\quad\|a\|=1\}$$

So $x,y\in S$

---

**2.** $\|x+y\|=2$, so the sum of $x$ and $y$ gives a point outside of the unit sphere, at distance two from the origin.

---

**3.** Knowing they are linearly independent, we know that $ax+by=0\iff a=b=0$

---

I have no idea what is meant by a line segment though, nor do I see why it is in the unit sphere. What are they wanting?

Comment: You need to find points $x$ and $y$ in $S_X$ such that $\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y$ is in $S_X$ for all $0\le \lambda\le 1$.

Comment: Isn't it true that $\| x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ iff $x$ and $y$ are lin. dependent?

Comment: Based on a couple of your earlier questions, I'm guessing some of your question comes down to terminology, particularly the meanings of "vector" and "sphere". In pure mathematics, the term "vector" has inequivalent (but overlapping) meanings depending on context: an element of a "vector space", a displacement between points in a Cartesian space, an infinitesimal displacement on a manifold, etc.... If you're coming from a physics background, the ambiguity is even greater. Separately, a "sphere" and a "ball" are not the same thing; do you mean "ball" in your question?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe no, take $l^1$-norm for $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$.

Comment: @daw. The equivalence is true if the norm arises from an inner product and if $y=\lambda x$ for nonnegative $\lambda$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: in that case, $x $ and $y $ are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me argue that the whole segment between $x$ and $y$ is in $S$.
For $t\in[0,1]$ set $x_t:=x+t(y-x)$. Then $x_0=x$, $x_1=y$, $x_{1/2}$ are all in $S$ by assumption: $\|x_t\|=1$ for $t\in \{0,1/2,1\}$.

By convexity of the norm, we obtain immediately that $\|x_t\|\le 1$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

Convexity not only tells us something about the function values on the segment between two points, but also about the function values on the line outside the segment:
$$
f(\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v)\ge \lambda f(u) + (1-\lambda)f(v) \quad \forall \lambda\not\in [0,1].
$$
Applying this to points $x_t$ with $t\in (0,1/2)$ and using $\|x_{1/2}\|=\|x_1\|=1$ yields $\|x_t\|\ge 1$ for $t\in (0,1/2)$. Similar arguments work for $t\in (1/2,1)$.

Hence $\|x_t\|=1$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, and we have found a line segment in the sphere.

Comment: So if this was taken to be in a euclidean space, this line segment would trace along the surface of the sphere? But that doesn't make sense in terms of building a straight line connecting $x_0$ and $x_1$

Comment: This is not possible in Euclidean space (or any space with strictly convex norm). It is possible in $\mathbb R^n$ supplied with $l_1$ or $l_\infty$ norm.

Comment: Sorry to bump this old question, but why does outside the segment, so $t\in(-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)$ we have $\|t u +(1- t) v) \| \geq t\|u \| + (1-t)\|v\|$?

Comment: Or more to the point you used $t\in (\frac 12,1)$ and used it, how is that?

Comment: @Exodus Convexity!  For $t>1$ rearrange points such that $u$ is between $v$ and $tu+(1-t)v$.

Comment: I don't understand, could you explain what you mean when you apply that to points $x_t$ with $t\in (0,\frac12)$?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the information gained outside the line segment

Comment: Thanks I guess I got it a different way. Assume that $\|tx_1 + (1-t)x_0\|\lt 1$ then:
$$1=\left\|\frac12 x_1 + \frac12 x_0\right\| = \left\|\frac{1-2t}{2(1-t)}x_1 + \frac{1}{2(1-t)}(tx_1+(1-t)x_0)\right\|$$

$$\implies1 = \frac{1-2t}{2(1-t)}\|x_1\| + \frac{1}{2(1-t)} \| tx_1 + (1-t)x_0)\|$$

$$\implies1 = \frac{1-2t}{2(1-t)}+ \frac{1}{2(1-t)} \| tx_1 + (1-t)x_0)\| \lt 1$$

Answer (score 3):

We claim that the line segment joining $x$ and $y$ is in the unit sphere:

Set $x_t=tx_1+ (1-t)x_0, t\in [0,1]$ and $x_1=x,x_0=y$. Now since the norm is convex, we have that:

$$\|x_t\| = \|tx_1+(1-t)x_0\| \leq t\|x_1\| + (1-t)\|x_0\|$$
$$\leq t+(1-t)=1$$

So we have that the line segment is in the closed unit ball, we need to show that it isn't in the open unit ball.

Assume that $\|tx_1 + (1-t)x_0\|\lt 1$ then:
$$1=\left\|\frac12 x_1 + \frac12 x_0\right\| = \left\|\frac{1-2t}{2(1-t)}x_1 + \frac{1}{2(1-t)}(tx_1+(1-t)x_0)\right\|$$

$$\implies1 = \frac{1-2t}{2(1-t)}\|x_1\| + \frac{1}{2(1-t)} \| tx_1 + (1-t)x_0)\|$$

$$\implies1 = \frac{1-2t}{2(1-t)}+ \frac{1}{2(1-t)} \| tx_1 + (1-t)x_0)\| \lt 1$$

Contradiction, hence $\|tx_1+(1-t)x_0\| \geq 1$

Hence we have  $\|tx_1+(1-t)x_0\| \geq 1,\quad t\in[0,1]$ and $\|tx_1+(1-t)x_0\| \leq 1,\quad t\in[0,1]$

It follows that $\|tx_1+(1-t)x_0\| = 1,\quad \forall t\in [0,1]$