# Convex function outside of segment

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I understand that a convex function has:

$$f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y),\quad t\in[0,1]$$

But I don't understand why this turns around for $t\in \Bbb R\backslash[0,1]$.

$$f(tx+(1-t)y)\geq tf(x) + (1-t)f(y),\quad t\in\Bbb R\backslash[0,1]$$

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: I don't think the second formula is required for definition of a convex function. Could you give a citation of a source for the second formula?

Comment: @coffeemath I saw it in this accepted answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394357/295840

Answer (score 1):

It's clear if you draw the right picture...

Ok. To be definite, let's suppose that $x<y$ and $t<0$. Let $$z=tx+(1-t)y.$$
Now $$z=y+t(x-y)>y.$$

So $x<y<z$, hence $y$ is a convex combination of $x$ and $z$. Sure enough, if you do a little algebra you see that $$y=sx+(1-s)z,$$where $$s=\frac{t}{t-1}\in(0,1).$$So $f$ convex shows that $$f(y)\le sf(x)+(1-s)f(z),$$and if you insert $s=t/(t-1)$ and do a little algebra that last inequality becomes precisely $$f(z)\ge tf(x)+(1-t)f(y).$$

You could say "Similarly for $t>1$" or, better, you could show that the case $t>1$ follows from the case $t<0$...